# Splash Screen Image is too Stretched

Tags: xml, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

I have Images in my drawable folders and I have them sized into the standard sizes and put them in each folder. But when i start my app and the MainActivity runs, my SplashScreen image appears stretched and looks bad on the screen. I have looked at answers online and nothing worked.

What can i do to make the image look normal on the splashscreen.

This is my MainActivity.cs

```
        [Activity(Label = "Peppy", Icon = "@mipmap/bicon", Theme = "@style/peppy", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
        public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
           protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));            
        }
    }
```

And this is my how I am defining my style in style.xml

```
 <style name="peppy" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bluesplash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Main Theme" parent="MainTheme.Base"></style>
```

I want the SplashScreen Image to fit perfectly on the screen as I want them to be. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a splashScreen.xml in my drawables folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/green_colour"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

That centres the image without distorting it.

The activity is like this

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Util;
using App1.Droid;

namespace com.xamarin.sample.splashscreen
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashActivity).Name;

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
            Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
        }

        // Launches the startup task
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }

        // Prevent the back button from canceling the startup process
        public override void OnBackPressed() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you also have a style that references that drawable in splashScreen.xml?

Comment: A more complete example (similar to this answer) is found in docs: [Creating a Drawable for the Splash Screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen#creating-a-drawable-for-the-splash-screen). The section after that one, "Implementing a Theme", shows how the splash screen xml is used.